# how can I create a data-container only using docker-compose.yml?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, volumes

This question is coming from an issue on the Docker's repository:
https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/942

I can't figure it out how to create a data container (no process running) with docker compose.

Comment: As of Docker 1.9, data-only containers can replaced with named containers https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/17798

Comment: In case you want to use named volumes to specify host mount point, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35841241/docker-compose-named-mounted-volume

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Things have changed in the last years. Please refer to the answer from @Frederik Wendt for a good and up-to-date solution.

**My old answer:** Exactly how to do it depends a little on what image you are using for your data-only-container. If your image has an `entrypoint`, you need to overwrite this in your `docker-compose.yml`. For example this is a solution for the official MySql image from docker hub:

```
DatabaseData:
  image: mysql:5.6.25
  entrypoint: /bin/bash

DatabaseServer:
  image: mysql:5.6.25
  volumes_from:
    - DatabaseData
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: blabla
```

When you do a `docker-compose up` on this, you will get a container like `..._DatabaseData_1` which shows a status of `Exited` when you call `docker ps -a`. Further investigation with `docker inspect` will show, that it has a timestamp of `0`. That means the container was never run. Like it is stated by the owner of docker compose [here](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/942#issuecomment-76547569).

Now, as long as you don't do a `docker-compose rm -v`, your data only container (`..._DatabaseData_1`) will not loose its data. So you can do `docker-compose stop` and `docker-compose up` as often as you like.

In case you like to use a dedicated data-only image like `tianon/true` this works the same. Here you don't need to overwrite the `entrypoint`, because it doesn't exist. It seems like there are some problems with that image and docker compose. I haven't tried it, but [this article](http://dockermeetupsinbordeaux.github.io/docker-compose/data-container/2015/03/01/minimalistic-docker-data-container.html) could be worth reading in case you experience any problems.

In general it seems to be a good idea to use the same image for your data-only container that you are using for the container accessing it. See [Data-only container madness](http://container42.com/2014/11/18/data-only-container-madness/) for more details.

Comment: I don't understand. Volume is a directory in the host filesystem that gets mapped into a container, right? Where is the volume here?

Comment: @crabman the [MySQL image](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/2e80e5ff6aa7d3a09723ad40f5954a0563dbac29/5.7/Dockerfile) has a volume specified. [volumes_from](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) tells docker to map that volume to the DatabaseData container instead.

Comment: @CrabMa, look inside the container which has volumes_from option (in your case Mysql container) / run # docker mysql_container inspect and see block Mounts [{Source: ""}]. "source" it is your path on host to container data

Answer (score 3):

The other answers to this question are quite out of date, and data volumes have been supported for some time now. Example:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  frontend:
    image: node:lts
    volumes:
      - myapp:/home/node/app
volumes:
  myapp:
```

See
https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#use-a-volume-with-docker-compose for details and options.

Answer (score 2):

A data only container (DOC) is a container that is created only to serve as a volume provider. The container itself has no function other than that other containers can mount it's volume by using the `volumes_from` directive.

The DOC has to run only once to create the volume. Other containers can reference the volumes in it even if it's stopped.

The OP Question:
The `docker-compose.yml` starts the DOC every time you do a `docker-compose up`. OP asks for an option to only create container and volume, and not run it, using some sort of an `create_only: true` option.

Answer (score 0):

As mention in the issue from the OP's question:

- you either create a data container with the same name as the one specified in the `docker-compose.yml`, and run `docker-compose up --no-recreate` (the one specified in `docker-compose.yml` won't be recreated).
- or you run a container with a simple command which never returns.
  Like: `tail -f /dev/null`