# What does volume_from do if there are no volumes in the volume container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am looking at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32916890/271388 and I don't fully understand what's going on there.

If I understand it right, in docker volume is a mapping from host filesystem into container's filesystem. And docker's --volumes-from flag as well as docker-compose's `volumes_from` directive in docker-compose.yml copies these mappings from one container to another.

But what's going on in that answer? There are no volumes mentioned in docker-compose.yml. What does the following do there?

```
  volumes_from:
    - DatabaseData
```

Answer (score 1):

A docker image can have its own volumes that are not defined at container creation (for instance, with the `-v` parameter of `docker run`), but when the image it *built*. That's what the `VOLUME` statement in a Dockerfile is for.

See also the [relevant section of the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume):

> The VOLUME instruction creates a mount point with the specified name and marks it as holding externally mounted volumes from native host or other containers. The value can be a JSON array, `VOLUME ["/var/log/"]`, or a plain string with multiple arguments, such as `VOLUME /var/log` or `VOLUME /var/log /var/db`. For more information/examples and mounting instructions via the Docker client, refer to Share Directories via Volumes documentation.
>
> The docker run command initializes the newly created volume with any data that exists at the specified location within the base image. For example, consider the following Dockerfile snippet:
>
> ```
> FROM ubuntu
> RUN mkdir /myvol
> RUN echo "hello world" > /myvol/greeting
> VOLUME /myvol
> ```

If you have a look at the [Dockerfile of the `mysql` image](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/ee6ac037ab647e0de9dbeb4e064610a95cb6df4a/5.7/Dockerfile#L40) that you're (indirectly) referring to in your question, you'll see that `/var/lib/mysql` is defined as a volume. Every container created from that image will be created with that volume, even if not explicitly defined.