# Local development with docker - do I need 2 Dockerfiles?

Tags: django, docker, dockerfile

Trying to dockerize a django project for the first time, I understand that for production my Dockerfile should have `ADD` that copies the django project to the container.

But for local development I need every change to the code to take effect immediately, for that I read it's recommended to mount a volume when I run docker ( docker run -v path:path ) but does that mean I need to have a different Dockerfile for local development? one that doesn't run the `ADD` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for 2 dockerfiles, if you mount with "docker run -v hostpath:containerpath" it mounts hostpath even if containerpath already exists!

Answer (score 5):

No you may not need two files. You can use same folder in ADD command in volume.

See this django tutorial from official docker page:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:2.7
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/
```

**Compose file**

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding a local folder to a container path, you could create a volume that can perists anywhere you want (as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36321403/6309) with the [local persist pluging driver](https://github.com/CWSpear/local-persist) or even with a [more advanced driver like flocker](https://clusterhq.com/2015/12/09/difference-docker-volumes-flocker-volumes/))

That way, your data persists in a data volume which can be accessed:

- either locally (local persist plugin)
- or still locally, through a dedicated container ([`svendowideit/samba/`](https://hub.docker.com/r/svendowideit/samba/)) mounting that volume

Comment: I would also recommend this solution. Flocker is now by default in Docker so it's easy to use.