# How to specify the size of a shared Docker volume?

Tags: docker, docker-volume

If I would like to create a data volume of let´s say 15GB that would be of type ext4, how would I do that?

`docker volume create --name vol` just creates an empty volume.

`docker volume create --opt type=ext4 --name vol` creates an ext4 volume but I cannot specify the size of it since ext4 does not support it according to the mount options of ext4.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is possible to specify the size limit while creating the docker volume using `size` as per the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/)

Here is example command provided in the documentation to specify the same

> docker volume create -d flocker -o size=20GB my-named-volume

**UPDATE** Some more examples from [git repository](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/11cd64f0dce35ad897ede7eb29babdc487e99617/cli/command/volume/create.go):

> The built-in **local** driver on Linux accepts options similar to the linux
>   **mount** command:
>       $ docker volume create --driver local --opt type=tmpfs --opt device=tmpfs --opt o=size=100m,uid=1000
>   **Another example:**
>       $ docker volume create --driver local --opt type=btrfs --opt device=/dev/sda2

Comment: Amazing that I have to search StackOverflow for `The built-in local driver on Linux accepts options similar to the linux mount command` because that piece of information is not listed on any relevant page of the official Docker documentation (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference, https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/ or https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/select-storage-driver/).

Comment: For those interested or who would find it helpful, some links to the linux `mount` command documentation: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html and http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/mount.htm

Comment: Also in case it's useful - here's a link to another StackOverflow posting that mentions a different local storage volume type that actually allows you to select the location for it on the host: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36321403/368896

Comment: For readers: a now-deleted answer claimed the above answer would/does not work, and referred to [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52089499/create-docker-volume-with-limited-size/52097560#52097560).

Comment: Docker Desktop on Windows seems unable to use `-o size=20GB` option.

Answer (score 16):

Using Docker Compose I was able to do it the following way:

```
volumes: 
  tmpfs: 
    # For details, see:
    # https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/#driver-specific-options
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      o: "size=$TMPFS_SIZE"
      device: tmpfs
      type: tmpfs
```

Answer (score 2):

Leaning on the answer of Rao, there are now some udpated docs and example on their docs.docker page:

- [Create a volume and pass the size option with the `opt` flag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/#driver-specific-options)

This example volume creation is taken from this page:

```
$ docker volume create --driver local \
--opt type=tmpfs \
--opt device=tmpfs \
--opt o=size=100m,uid=1000 \
foo
```