# Create docker volume with limited size

Tags: docker, docker-volume

There is is very limited information regarding create volume with options "https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/ ".

I just want to create a volume with limited size, I tried,

```
docker volume create --opt o=size=10m hello-volume
```

, when run a simple hello world container with “docker run -v hello-volume:/hello -it ubuntu /bin/bash”, I got the error as something like “docker: Error response from daemon: …no such device”…

So I assumed we must give the full options when creating the volume, such as

```
“docker volume create --driver local --opt type=*** --opt device=*** --opt o=size=10m hello-volume”
```

?
If so, what are the “type” and “device” here? I guess the device actually is a path to any directory? I tried

```
“docker volume create --driver local --opt type=volume --opt device=/ --opt o=size=10m hello-volume”.
```

When tried to run the container as “docker run -v hello-volume:/hello -it ubuntu /bin/bash” I got the error as “docker: Error response from daemon: error while mounting volume ‘/var/lib/docker/volumes/hello-volume/_data’: error while mounting volume with options: type=‘volume’ device=’/’ o=‘size=10m’: no such device.”.

I tried

```
docker volume create --driver local --opt type=tmpfs --opt device=tmpfs --opt o=size=10m hello-volume
```

which finally works, but the data is in memory which is not persistent. So can any one point out what are the options for “type” and “device” when creating the volume (or what’s the default one if we don’t give any options)?

**Update:**

Just want to update that it seems there is no way to limit the disk size in local driver with ext4 type (although claimed doable in several answers and other posts). The major reason is there is no such "size" parameter in "ext4" file system..
I created a docker volume:

```
docker volume create --driver local --opt type=ext4 --opt device=/dev/xvdf --opt o=size=10m hello-volume
```

Then inspect it (docker volume inspect hello-volume), and mount it with a container, everything looks fine for now.

```
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2018-09-01T04:23:57Z",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {},
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/hello-volume/_data",
        "Name": "hello-volume",
        "Options": {
            "device": "/dev/xvdf",
            "o": "size=10m",
            "type": "ext4"
        },
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]

docker run -v hello-volume:/myfile1 -exec -it ubuntu /bin/bash
```

But when you write/put a large file (larger than 10m) in the "/myfile1" in that container, no alert/exception is thrown, the write succeeded. What I think is that "o=size=10m" is not recognized by ext4 type file system.

Answer (score 6):

This is actually possible using dockers `local` volume driver. This driver accepts options similar to the linux [mount](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html) options. Check out this excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40499023/10109833).

You were close with your attempt. You need to specify a `--opt device=` as well as a `--opt type=` option. This will essentially mount a block device on your host into your docker container as a volume. The `type` option specifies the filesystem type to use. The `device` option requires you to specify one of the block devices on your host - `/dev/sda2` for example. You can see a complete list by running `lsblk`.

However, it would be a bad idea to map existing drives (unless they are unused). So you will need to create a new block device (using `lvm` or equivalent), or for testing you can use volatile storage (tmpfs), as you have tried.

Comment: thanks for the answer. So if I understand correctly, the best option is to use the local volume driver with things like "docker volume create -d flocker -o size=20GB my-named-volume"? Can you provide some hint/guideline what's local driver? Thank you

Comment: The `local` driver is the default volume driver used by docker when creating volumes. Without any options, this mounts directories and files within a filesystem as volumes. But with the options specified above it mounts the entire block device. My answer was related to this driver. `flocker` is a separate volume driver. I haven't used it myself, but it probably does what you want.

Comment: hi @rahoogan. Thank you for your answer in detail. But please check my update. After some experiments I don't think we can create a volume with specific size with local driver type ext4.  The "o=size=10m" won't be recognized by ext4. Have to cancel the accepted answer. Please correct if I am wrong.

Comment: @batilei How large is /dev/xvdf ? Your volume will have to be the same size as that. Also might be worth posting this update as a new question on ServerFault. You might get more answers.

Comment: thanks. The "/dev/xvdf" is like 60GB I think. But if set "volume will have to be the same size as that.", I think there is no point setting up the limit. Let me post on the ServerFault. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Docker volumes have "drivers" attached to them.  [The default driver is one called "local"](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/#driver-specific-options) and all it does is creates a directory in `/var/lib/docker` and mounts it to the container.  There's no option to specify (or limit) the volume's size.

Answer (score 1):

I solved issue for limiting space on docker volumes (by binding dir with -v) using [xfs_quota](https://linux.die.net/man/8/xfs_quota)

Location where I needed to store data is a XFS volume mounted with prjquota option

```
#~ mount 
/dev/mapper/centos_ssp--forfiter--07-home on /home type xfs (rw,[..],**prjquota**)
```

I think that kernel must support it (rootflags=pquota kernel options)

Example from above link:

```
Enabling project quota on an XFS filesystem (restrict files in log file directories to only using 1 gigabyte of space).
# mount -o prjquota /dev/xvm/var /var
# echo 42:/var/log >> /etc/projects
# echo logfiles:42 >> /etc/projid
# xfs_quota -x -c 'project -s logfiles' /var
# xfs_quota -x -c 'limit -p bhard=1g logfiles' /var
```

There is also a plugin for docker [cirocosta/xfsvol](https://github.com/cirocosta/xfsvol)