# Max size volumes in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When starting several services using the docker-compose.yml, I see that the folder /var/lib/docker/volumes/ grows in size continuously without stopping.
How can I limit the maximum size I can use or how can I clean that folder in the docker-compose.yml file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create docker volume with limited size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52089499/create-docker-volume-with-limited-size)