# ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', volume must be a mapping not a string

Tags: wordpress, docker-compose, docker-volume

**Question:**
Why do I get this error?

> ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', volume 'mariavolume' must be a mapping not a string.

My docker-compose file is almost identical to this one: https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: example
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: 3306
  db:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    volumes:
      - maria_volume: /var/lib/mysql
volumes:
  maria_volume: ~/mariadb
```

Answer (score 23):

In my case this was happening because I missed adding a `:` after the volume name.

Instead of:

```
volumes:
    - mysqldata:
```

I had typed:

```
volumes:
    - mysqldata
```

`docker-compose up` gave me the same error as above.

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately, there is no such a feature.

You can’t map a top-level volume in docker-compose.

Here are the options:

- Adding volume per container and map it there. (like what Daniel did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41346284/1954233))
- Create a volume outside of the compose (with mapping) and use it in your compose.

  ```
  volumes:
     maria_volume: 
         external:
             name: volume-name
  ```

Comment: This is not true, you can map the top-level volume as well.

Answer (score 11):

I've just tackled this issue myself. If you just want a volume to store data, then do as below. This will create/reuse a `volume` that is persisted to disk as part of the `Docker` graph driver.

The next question is **where is this?**.

You can find it inside the docker image - Default Location -

> C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual hard disks

```
db:
  image: mariadb
  restart: always
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
  volumes:
    - maria_volume: /var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  maria_volume:
```

Of course, if you are after mapping a host directory into docker rather than having it inside the `Docker` graph driver. Then you can do it as follows.

```
db:
  image: mariadb
  restart: always
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
  volumes:
    - maria_volume: /var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  maria_volume:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      o: bind
      type: none
      device: /C/mariadb
```

Please note, when mapping over host directories as volume (at least on windows) you can have issues with `read/write` permissions, something I have yet to resolve myself.

Comment: Thank you, it's worked for me :) you saved my day :)

Comment: Hi, just wondering if you find a solution for the read/write permissions issues on Windows, thanks.

Comment: @bouchepat I found on Windows that moving your data out of the WSL linux partition and onto your drive e.g. /c/docker/data fixed read/write permissions for me

Comment: This worked for me, but I am using Linux, normally this is `/var/lib/docker` and there is the folder volumes. To find your docker root dir just type `docker info | grep "Docker Root Dir"`

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
    volumes:
        - maria_volume: /var/lib/mysql
volumes:
    maria_volume: 
        external:
            name: ~/mariadb
```

Comment: Thanks, but that gives me this syntax error: `volumes.maria_volume.external contains an invalid type, it should be a boolean, or an object
`

Comment: space is important: `name:<space>...`

Answer (score 2):

correct syntax for volume is
 
`volumes:
    first:`

 where first is just a placeholder name to be used for volume

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  ...
  db:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    volumes:
      - ~/mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
```

Answer (score 1):

try this, it works for me

```
   volumes:
     - maria_volume: /var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  maria_volume: 
    drive: local
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue as yourself and as a last act of despair I tried putting

```
volumes:
  - maria_volume: /var/lib/mysql
```

before

```
environment:
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
```

I'm not sure what kind of magic applied here but in my case, it worked

Let me know!

Comment: Thanks, yes this works, but then you're no longer using a single named volume throughout your compose file, you're manually doing it per service version 1 docker-compose style hardcoded to the folder

Answer (score -1):

For me this works:

In #docker_compose.yml:

```
volumes:
  postgres_data: {}
  static: { }
```