# How do I create an external volume using docker compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, node-red

Basing on this [Node-RED tutorial](https://nodered.org/docs/getting-started/docker), I'm trying to mount an external volume with the Node-RED files outside the docker machine. I'm using the following `docker-compose` file:

```yaml
version: "3.7"

services:
  node-red:
    image: nodered/node-red:latest
    environment:
      - TZ=Europe/Amsterdam
    ports:
      - "2000:1880"
    networks:
      - node-red-net
    volumes:
      - node-red-data:/home/user/node-red1
    
volumes:
  node-red-data:
    
networks:
  node-red-net:
```

However, even though this file works fine when I run `docker-compose up`, the volume exists only inside the docker machine. I've tried adding the line `external: true` in `volumes` but I get the following error:

```
ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', volume 'external' must be a mapping not a boolean.
```

What am I missing? How do I mount an external volume using docker-compose files?

Comment: Are you actually using Docker Machine (or Docker Toolbox)?  Where do you want the volume to be?

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm using the command line docker-compose... I've added the official docker repository on Ubuntu and installed it with `sudo apt install docker-compose`. The application runs fine when I run `docker-compose`, the only problem is that the volume is not mounted outside docker... Only inside it... I'd like the volume to be on a path that I have on Ubuntu.

Comment: You might look at the [Compose `volumes:` syntax for bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#short-syntax-3) in the Compose file reference.  ("External" volumes are named volumes, still not directly accessible from the host, that happen to be created outside of this particular Compose file.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding a related question with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56064476/14739472). There are multiple answers that didn't work for me there (also there's no accepted answer). The syntax that worked was:

```yaml
  node-red-data:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      o: bind
      type: none
      device: /path/external/folder
```

So the final `dockerfile` that works after running `docker-compose up` is:

```yaml
version: "3.7"

services:
  node-red:
    image: nodered/node-red:latest
    environment:
      - TZ=Europe/Amsterdam
    ports:
      - "2000:1880"
    networks:
      - node-red-net
    volumes:
      - node-red-data:/data
    container_name: node-red

volumes:
  node-red-data:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      o: bind
      type: none
      device: "/home/user/node-red1"
networks:
  node-red-net:
```

---

**Update**

If we don't mind having a random name for the volume, the following solution also works fine:

```yaml
version: "3.7"

services:
  node-red:
    image: nodered/node-red:latest
    environment:
      - TZ=Europe/Amsterdam
    ports:
      - "2000:1880"
    volumes:
      - /home/user/node-red1:/data
    container_name: node-red
```