# How can I mount an absolute host path as a named volume in docker-compose?

Tags: docker-compose

I've already tried the solution in [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35841241/docker-compose-named-mounted-volume). It did not work for me, as shown below.

Here's my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    volumes:
     - data:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  data:
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: /usr/local/opt/mysql/mywebsite.com
      o: bind
```

Here's the result of `docker-compose up`:

```
$ docker-compose up
Creating volume "mycontainer_data" with default driver
Recreating 45bc03b2c674_mycontainer_db_1 ... error

ERROR: for 45bc03b2c674_mycontainer_db_1  Cannot create container for service db: error while mounting volume with options: type='none' device='/usr/local/opt/mysql/mywebsite.com' o='bind': no such file or directory

ERROR: for db  Cannot create container for service db: error while mounting volume with options: type='none' device='/usr/local/opt/mysql/mywebsite.com' o='bind': no such file or directory
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Instead of `type: none`, I have also tried `type: volume` and `type: bind`, but I got the same error.

The directory clearly exists:

```
$ ls -al /usr/local/opt/mysql/
...
drwxr-xr-x   2 cameronhudson  staff      64 Jun 10 10:32 mywebsite.com
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were 2 reasons why my configuration wasn't working.

First, **Docker does not follow symlinks**, and the `mysql` directory is a symlink:

```
$ ls -al /usr/local/opt | grep mysql
lrwxr-xr-x    1 cameronhudson  admin    22 Jan 23 17:42 mysql -> ../Cellar/mysql/8.0.13
```

However, even after using a path without any symlinks, `/databases/mywebsite.com`, I continued the experience the same `no such file or directory` error.

I found that if I changed my `docker-compose.yml` file to mount this directory as a nameless volume, I got a different, more reasonable error:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    volumes:
     - /databases/mywebsite.com:/var/lib/mysql
```

The new error:

```
ERROR: for mycontainer_db_1  Cannot start service db: b'Mounts denied: \r\nThe path /databases/mywebsite.com\r\nis not shared from OS X and is not known to Docker.\r\nYou can configure shared paths from Docker -> Preferences... -> File Sharing.\r\nSee https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#namespaces for more info.\r\n.'
```

After **I added this path in Docker Desktop**, I was able to `up` the services using my original configuration. It also worked with `type: none`, `type: volume`, `type: bind`, or leaving `type` out altogether.

Comment: What do you mean "added this path in Docker Desktop"?

Comment: @Slav Docker Desktop is a package from Docker. Installing it installs the docker CLI and daemon. More info here: https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop

Comment: Yes, I have Docker Desktop installed. It shows running containers, and allows to start/stop/delete/inspect them. Where in Docker Desktop can you "add a path" to a volume?

Comment: @Slav Docker Desktop -> Preferences -> Resources -> File Sharing