# docker failed to mount local volume mount no such file or directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to run my image like this:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  gamit:
    image: myimage
    volumes:
      - app:/app
volumes:
  app:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: ./app
      o: bind
```

At first my goal was to have an `app` directory near my `docker-compose.yml` file that (app directory) should persist an `app` directory from inside a container (it already contains some important data). My deploy scenario assumes that this directory is initially empty on host and then keeps up with changes from inside container. When I was running it with `docker compose up` my `app` directory near the `docker-compose.yml` remained empty. I noticed that `/var/lib/docker/volumes/myimage/_data` was created and populated with data from container (I assumed from another stackoverflow questions that my `device: ./app` option sets the location of host directory). Then I've removed `/var/lib/docker/volumes/myimage/` directory and now it throws me an error `docker failed to mount local volume mount no such file or directory`.
My general goal is to initially run `docker compose up` with an empty `app` directory, populate it from inside the container and then have all changes from inside the container in it.

Comment: You shouldn't usually change anything in `/var/lib/docker`, and deleting the volume directory there almost certainly caused the error you see now.  Can you use the shorter `volumes: ['./app:/app']` bind-mount syntax instead?

Comment: Is this off topic ? You may ask on serverfault.com

Comment: @DavidMaze Have tried to run with shorter `volumes: ['./app:/app']` bind-mount syntax. It has created an empty `app` directory near my `docker-compose.yml` file and `app` directory inside the container became empty. My goal is to have this directory with data from inside the container.

Comment: I finally found the answer here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70326574/named-volume-with-local-bind-defined-in-docker-compose-not-working-but-working-wx#new-answer)

Answer (score 8):

In ubuntu 20.04, Docker version 20.10.17 and Docker compose version v2.6.0

I try to use: **${PWD}/app** instead of **./app**. like this:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  gamit:
    image: myimage
    volumes:
      - app:/app
volumes:
  app:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: ${PWD}/app
      o: bind
```

It works fine for me. As I know for the local volume In Docker, you need to have an absolute path for mounting. **${PWD}** environment variable shows the current path of your project. But sometimes **${PWD}** in some versions of Docker or some versions of Docker Compose do not work well!

There is suitable information at https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/

Comment: Thanks, adding absolute path resolved the issue for me as well.

Comment: This does not work when using docker as sudo, then you need the absolute path or you need to manually set PWD