# is there is any way we can use bind mount in dockerfile or it neccessary to use compose-file.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm, docker-registry

how can we use below sample code in Docker-file

sample 1
`docker container run -p 80:4000 -v $(pwd):/site/jekyll-serve`
sample 2
`docker container run -p 8080:80 --name web2 -v $(pwd):/usr/share/nginx/html nginx`

i have recently started learning docker and swarm orchestration just need to know about this issue. is there any update in future release or any fixes to this....???

Answer (score 0):

as of 9/9/21 you need to use docker compose

https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

```
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:4000"
```

https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

```
services:
  frontend:
    volumes:
      -  $(pwd):/site/jekyll-serve
volumes:
  myapp:
```

Named volumes: [Docker-compose named mounted volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35841241/docker-compose-named-mounted-volume)

```
my-named-volume:
     driver_opts:
           type: none
           device: /home/full/path #NOTE needs full path (~ doesn't work)
           o: bind
```

Comment: ok thanks...!!! can you share me how to add named volumes named volumes..for this..

Comment: Someone else has already answered that throughly here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35841241/docker-compose-named-mounted-volume

Comment: you need $(pwd) when calling docker directly. But compose supports relative paths. `./:/site/jekyll-serve` is sufficient.