# Seeding a MySQL DB for a Dockerized Django App

Tags: mysql, django, docker, docker-compose

I am tasked with creating a click-button style use of Docker for developers of a Django app to do local development.

I am using `docker-compose` in combination with private repos on my Docker Hub and it's working well.

Except that the app has no default data.  The developers have requested to use a full prod dump rather than fixtures with `loaddata`.

Therefore I built a container based on this Dockerfile

```
FROM python:2.7

COPY . /opt/mysite.com
WORKDIR /opt/mysite.com

ENV WAITFORIT_VERSION="v1.3.1"
RUN wget -q -O /usr/local/bin/waitforit https://github.com/maxcnunes/waitforit/releases/download/$WAITFORIT_VERSION/waitforit-linux_amd64 \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/waitforit

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash -
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install mysql-client nodejs

RUN pip install -r requirements/local.txt

RUN npm install
RUN ./node_modules/.bin/babel-node ./node_modules/.bin/webpack

CMD waitforit -full-connection=tcp://mysql:3306 -timeout=60 -debug && mysql -u root -h mysql --password=**** mysite_develop < prod.sql && /bin/bash -c "source /opt/mysite.com/env.local && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput && python /opt/mysite.com/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:5000"
```

All works well except that it takes a very long time to be able to see `localhost:5000` after the containers are up.

Therefore I started to [investigate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32908621/how-can-i-create-a-data-container-only-using-docker-compose-yml) `data-only` containers, but I am wondering what happens when I push that container to Docker hub? Can it be pulled with the mysql data baked onto from `docker-compose`?

If not, then how can I fix the above `Dockerfile`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL (and variants like Percona Server) provide a facility for seeding a database on first container start described in the "Initializing a fresh instance" section in the [docker hub page](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/).

> When a container is started for the first time, a new database with
>   the specified name will be created and initialized with the provided
>   configuration variables. Furthermore, it will execute files with
>   extensions .sh, .sql and .sql.gz that are found in
>   /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d. Files will be executed in alphabetical
>   order. You can easily populate your mysql services by mounting a SQL
>   dump into that directory and provide custom images with contributed
>   data. SQL files will be imported by default to the database specified
>   by the MYSQL_DATABASE variable.

A Dockerfile using this technique will look like

```
FROM mysql:8
COPY seed-data.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

Note: the directory trailing slash is important.

When you `docker run` this image, docker will create the container, the [docker-entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/dc60c4b80f3eb5b7ef8b9ae09f16f6fab7a2fbf5/8.0/docker-entrypoint.sh) will execute the sql script, and then the container will be ready to serve data.

Data will persist through container restarts - the seed data and subsequent modifications.

You can reuse the container for faster startup times - subsequent container starts will not need to initialize the database or seed the data.
When you need pristine data, delete the container and `docker run` the image again.

When you delete the container, remember to delete the docker volume containing the db data: `docker rm -v $CONTAINER_NAME`.

I use this method to provide [standard data](https://github.com/stevetarver/sample-data) for language / framework POCs as well as CI/CD. Initializing a new database and seeding large amounts of data can take a couple of minutes so you will want some logic to pause automated operations until you can successfully make a db connection.

Hope this helps you on your way.